# Solving non linear ODE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, nonlinear-system

I've been trying to solve the following ODE

$$
4 x\left(y(x) \times \frac{\partial^{2} y(x)}{\partial x^{2}}+\left(\frac{\partial y(x)}{\partial x}\right)^{2}\right)+2 y(x) \times \frac{\partial y(x)}{\partial x}+y(x)^{2} x k \times \frac{\partial y(x)}{\partial x}=0,
$$

with $x = \psi^2/t, \ u(\psi,t)=y(x), \ u(\psi,0)=N_0 \delta(\psi)$,
but unfortunately I'm at a loss.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

## 1. *y* = *y(x)* or *y* = *y(x, t)*?

The differential equation establishes that *y* is a function only of *x*, ie: *y* = *y(x)*.

However, your boundary condition establishes that *y* is a function of something else, maybe time? *y* = *y(x, t)*?

## 2. What kind of answer?

Are you looking for **analytical** or **numerical** solutions?

## 3. Possible solution path

This kind of problem is usually solved by **integral transform techniques** or by **finite elements**. However, you would have to explain better the problem and what you are trying to achieve in order to decide which one would be the best.

Comment: Sorry. Thanks for the first point. I had made a mistake when formulating the question. Idealy I'm looking for an analytical solution, although even a numerical solution would be a good start

Comment: @FrancescoAzzollini > "x=ψ²/t, u(ψ,t)=y(x)" Ok, it looks like you are using some kind of self similarity. This is a well known technique.

Comment: @FrancescoAzzollini > "Idealy I'm looking for an analytical solution" Probably there are some analytical insights you can obtain. I have already seen nastier stuff with some interesting analytical approaches. However, my recommendation for you is the following:

Comment: @FrancescoAzzollini Instead of beginning with this tough problem, start with simple cases (ex: uni-dimensional heat transfer) and gradually increases the difficulty. There is a **plethora** of analytical approaches for such kind of equations in all sorts of engineering branches. After you've got familiar with that, then move forward to the tough problem you've posted.

Comment: @FrancescoAzzollini > "although even a numerical solution would be a good start" The same is true for numerical approaches. Start with easier stuff that has already been studied at deep.